# Why is length equal to 0 in browser before it is defined?

Tags: javascript

I would expect the value of an undefined variable in javascript to behave like this when it is logged:

[image]

But on jsfiddle it is showing the `length` is 0 before it is ever defined.

[image]

After more research. It also seems to default to 0 in chrome.

[image]

When I would expect it to generate an error like with any other `randomWord`

[image]

When I run the same commands in node locally, it seems to behave how I would expect. With throwing an error for length:

[image]

Why is length equal to `0` in these cases?

Comment: what you are in effect doing is `console.log(window.length)` - which is defined in [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`length` is a predefined global variable in browsers:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)

> Returns the number of frames (either `<frame>` or `<iframe>` elements) in the window

Answer (score 1):

If you do not qualify `length` property then JS will go up the hierarchy and see if someone up the hierarchy has the property `length` and it happens to be that `window` has that property. Therefore, it is not undefined. It is defined.

It is the same as `window.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this： `console.log("length" in window)`, then you will know if it is defined in the global object.